# Only show parts of image under a div using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm displaying a background picture with some semi-opaque div over it, so that it appears somewhat darker than it actually is. On top if it, I have a number of smaller, draggable divs.

I'd like the image to be completely visible, or revealed under these divs. These smaller divs should be like looking through windows to the below image.

One way to do it, is to set the background of each "window div" be a version of the larger image, and adjust the position to compensate for the div location. This works okay, but is kind of slow/jerky and very clunky.

Is there a better way?
Thanks!

Comment: Maybe using a [canvas](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Canvas_tutorial)?

Comment: paste some code below of what you have achieved so far, so that people can tell you better...

Comment: We could better judge the validity of your methods by seeing your code.